# Working with multiple tables in SQLite WIndows Phone 8.1

Tags: database, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net

I worked with Database apps in Windows Phone 8.1 SDSK for the first time. I made a basic CRUD app with single DB following this [tutorial](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2015/01/windowsphone-81-sqlite-how-to-store.html).

Now I wanted to move on to using multiple tablesin a single app, like one is student details, other has student marks as foreign key. I could make two tables and use Primary key from one to the other but what is proper way to use foreign keys and doing other complex queries like joins etc? I haven't found any good documentations regarding this even on github pages of SQLite-NET.

I considered using SQLitePCL wrapper as well but again cannot find any documentation regarding multiplae DBs and complex queries, foreign key constraints etc.

How to proceed in this case? Any links or hints to proceed would be very helpful.

[ Also, there should be a SQLitePCL tag too, moderators/senior members if you think it is worthy? ]

EDIT- I meant multiple tables, not databases

Comment: May you using a Web Service? Long ago i published a paper for using WCF Service. Here is the service http://www.anggalisdiyanto.net/servis/ServisKPM.svc

Comment: You can't have foreign keys span across databases. It sounds like you want multiple tables instead.

Comment: Yes, i meant multiple tables only! Sorry for the typo. 
And this application is for learning multiple tables only, so no web service use, though looks quite interesting.